# How to show dataSet in WPF dataGrid with derived column names?

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset

I am using the following code:

```
dataGrid_Actions.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Which is fine but it returns the column headers as in the database. Of course, I need to make the headers user friendly. What would be a fast way to achieve that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This answer is *not* very practical, but is just being used to demonstrate how you could change the names of your `DataGrid.Columns`:

```
dataGrid_Actions.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGrid.Columns)
{
    column.Header = "Something";
}
```

Of course, you won't want all of your `DataGridColumn Header` values reading the same value, but I'm sure that you can work out how to set your own values for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Header text in the GridView's RowDataBound event, with something like:

```
Private Sub gvUsers_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvUsers.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
      For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
         e.Row.Cells(i).Text = "Col " & i.ToString
      Next
    End If
  End Sub
```

Similarly for datagrid you have `ItemDataBound` event. You can change the column name inside that event.

Comment: I am not really familiar with VB or whatever this is :(

Comment: I have converted the code to c#:                                   private void gvUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++) {
   e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "Col " + i.ToString();
  }
 }
}

Comment: @user2611292, might that C# be easier to read if you add it into your answer instead of putting it into a comment?